# PowerShell: Format Get-WmiObject output to return only the IP address

Tags: powershell, wmi

I would like to use Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration to return the ip address of a network card. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to format the output to display only the IPv.4 address.

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select IPAddress | Where-Object {$_.IPaddress -like "192.168*"}
```

Displays:

```
IPAddress
---------
{192.168.56.1, fe80::8980:15f4:e2f4:aeca}
```

Using the above output as an example, I would like it to only return 192.168.56.1 (Some clients have multiple NIC's, hence the "Where-Object")

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `IPAddress` property is a `string[]`, so the following should do it:

```
gwmi Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration |
    Where { $_.IPAddress } | # filter the objects where an address actually exists
    Select -Expand IPAddress | # retrieve only the property *value*
    Where { $_ -like '192.168.*' }
```

Comment: The above would only work for IPv4 addresses beginning "192.168.*".  If you replace the last Where clause with "{$_ -notlike '*:*'}" it will give you just the IPv4 address.

Comment: I needed to use `?{$_ -notlike "*:*"}`.

Answer (score 3):

Adding a quicker answer (avoiding Where-Object and using -like operation on a list):

```
@(@(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IPAddress) -like "*.*")[0]
```

Hope this Helps

Answer (score 1):

Thought I would share my own variation on the above, in case it helps someone. Just one line:

```
Get-WmiObject win32_networkadapterconfiguration | where { $_.ipaddress -like "1*" } | select -ExpandProperty ipaddress | select -First 1
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | where { (($_.IPEnabled -ne $null) -and ($_.DefaultIPGateway -ne $null)) } | select IPAddress -First 1).IPAddress[0]
```

Returns the IP-address of network connection with default gateway.
This is exactly what you need in most cases :)

Compatible with Powershell 2.0 (Windows XP) and newer.

Answer (score 0):

(Get-WmiObject win32_Networkadapterconfiguration | Where-Object{$_.ipaddress -notlike $null}).IPaddress | Select-Object -First 1

Hope that this will help !

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Answer (score 0):

```
(Get-WMIObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).IPAddress
```

Comment: Why do you prefer this formulation over existing answers that have been validated by the community?

Comment: I just préfet this formulation to ne very simple to return thé IP address without any other parameters.